# Micro Protection with Long Cables

Tags: microcontroller, protection, esd

I have a micro controller ATxmega128A1U ([datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8385-8-and-16-bit-avr-microcontroller-atxmega64a1u-atxmega128a1u_datasheet.pdf)) which will have switches and potentiometers attached to the GPIO and ADC input pins. These inputs will have about 2-3 meters of cabling from the panel to the micro-controller.

1) What sort of protection do I need to put on these inputs? Would a TVS diode arrays be necessary? (something like [this](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PRTR5V0U8S.pdf) perhaps)

2) What sort of filters do I need to put on the lines? Would some simple ferrite chips be enough and how do I chose a ferrite based on frequency response if I don't know what sort of noise may be coupled to the system when deployed?

3) Anything else I need to design for when having cabling this long?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What kind of bandwidth are you looking at getting out of your ADC inputs? Ferrites are only so-so protection. You could run common mode chokes if budget provides. Those ESD ICs look very nice. See this related question for some additional ideas: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28954/esd-protection-of-adc-input?rq=1

Comment: The ADCs will only be measuring the potentiometers via a resistor divider and the potentiometers will be toggled by a human so there is no fast signals here.

Comment: What kind of EMI environment will you unit operate in?  For example.  Bottom of the ocean - very quiet.  Arc welding shop - very strong EMI.

Comment: Living room of a standard home in North America, so except for florescent lamps I am not sure what else would cause issues.

Comment: In that case, you may use differential inputs to get better ADC readings. Additionally, series resistors [on the gpio] will limit any ESD current while still allowing the GPIO to function correctly. Wintertime is a recipe for static discharge!

Answer (score 2):

If all you're measuring is a voltage(DC Signal) with the ADC you can probably get away with just putting a small capacitor(~~22nf) to ground to ground along with a [voltage follower](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/opampvar2.html) [a very simple op amp configuration that basically relays a signal while giving the arduino some isolation from noise]. Pretty much any op amp you have laying around will work. An inductor (like one of the ring ones found in computers) in series with the signal wouldn't hurt either.
`

Comment: The board is not an Arduino. It's an XMEGA not a mega device. I wish to avoid adding active devices and want to provide the shielding/isolation only using passives.